# PHP Shopping cart // show results of different rows

Tags: php

Hell community, I am trying to build up a shopping cart which basically looks like an excel table.
The layout and the main code is working good but I can add only products from one row to the shopping cart table. My target is to choose and add as much products I want from row I want.

Here the code I am using:

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        { 
    ?>

    <div id="product">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
                <?php
                    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shop");
                    // Check connection
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }
                    $sql = "SELECT id, product, A, B, C, D, E FROM products";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $Id = $row ["id"];
                        $Product = $row ["product"];
                        $A = $row ["A"];
                        $B = $row ["B"];
                        $C = $row ["C"];
                        $D = $row ["D"];
                        $E = $row ["E"];

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["product"] . "</td><br />";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["A"] . "
                        <form id= \"Form_1\" method=\"post\" action=\"tbl_sc.php?action=add&id=$Id\">
                        <input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to cart\"></td><br />";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["B"] . "
                        <input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to cart\"></td><br />";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["C"] . "
                        <input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to cart\"></td><br />";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["D"] . "
                        <input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to cart\"></td><br />";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["E"] . "
                        <input name=\"hidden_name\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$Product\">
                        <input name=\"hidden_price\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$A\">
                        <input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to cart\"></td><br />";
                        echo "<td>
                        </form></td></tr>"; 
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    } else { echo "0 results"; }
                ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

What I have found out is that when I cklick th "Add to cart" button my code shows always only the content  in the shopping cart table of the variable which is mentioned in the "hidden_price" row. What do I have to add or change in the code to be able to add also the other rows (B, C, D...) to the shopping cart and to be able to choose a product from the row I want?

Thanks upfront for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not working this wat. You should either have a different form for each product wether use checkbox. Below is the code for the first case. Keep in mind **name** is how you call the field and **value** is "what you want to get from that field**.

When you use POST , you do not need something after action="somefile.php" this is what post does, "send all variables to the file somefile.php". Only problem with the below is that you need your tbl_sc.php after "posting" the data to redirect in the same page.

```
<div id="product">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
        </tr>
            <?php

                    $Id = "111";
                    $Product = "xx;";
                    $A = 1;
                    $B = 2;
                    $C = 3;
                    $D = 4;
                    $E = 5;

                    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>

<div id="product">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
        </tr>
            <?php
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shop");
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
                $sql = "SELECT id, product, A, B, C, D, E FROM products";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $Id = $row ["id"];
                    $Product = $row ["product"];
                    $A = $row ["A"];
                    $B = $row ["B"];
                    $C = $row ["C"];
                    $D = $row ["D"];
                    $E = $row ["E"];

                    echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>" . $row["product"] . "</td><br />";

                    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"tbl_sc.php\">";
                    echo "<td>$A <br>";
                    echo "<input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$A\">";
                    /* If you need to know also the row Id add the below and remove the ?action=add&id=$Id\ in action */
                    echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$id\">";
                    echo "<button type=\"submit\"> Add to Cart </button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</form>";

                    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"tbl_sc.php\">";
                    echo "<td>$B <br>";
                    echo "<input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$B\">";
                    /* If you need to know also the row Id add the below and remove the ?action=add&id=$Id\ in action */
                    echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$id\">";
                    echo "<button type=\"submit\"> Add to Cart </button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</form>";

                    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"tbl_sc.php\">";
                    echo "<td>$C <br>";
                    echo "<input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$C\">";
                    /* If you need to know also the row Id add the below and remove the ?action=add&id=$Id\ in action */
                    echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$id\">";
                      echo "<button type=\"submit\"> Add to Cart </button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</form>";

                    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"tbl_sc.php\">";
                    echo "<td>$D <br>";
                    echo "<input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$D\">";
                    /* If you need to know also the row Id add the below and remove the ?action=add&id=$Id\ in action */
                    echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$id\">";
                      echo "<button type=\"submit\"> Add to Cart </button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</form>";

                    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"tbl_sc.php\">";
                    echo "<td>$E <br>";
                    echo "<input name=\"add_to_cart\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$E\">";
                    /* If you need to know also the row Id add the below and remove the ?action=add&id=$Id\ in action */
                    echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$id\">";
                      echo "<button type=\"submit\"> Add to Cart </button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</form>";


                    echo "</tr>";



                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                } else { echo "0 results"; }
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
                echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hello Thomas, thanks for the quick support. I have been working on different issues on the site therefore my personal feedback to you is coming a little bit late. Your proposal was very good and useful. I have implemented it and it works as I wanted to. THANKS

Comment: I am glad I could help, you can click to accept the answer as correct. Regards, Thomas

Comment: Hello Thomas, thanks for the reminder, of course I have accepted the answer, regards